# How to run c# websockets over TLS when both client and server location are dynamic?

Tags: javascript, c#, ssl, certificate

I am trying to get a secured Websocket line going when both ends of the connection are on variable locations.

What im doing:

I have a c# program running a Websocket **server** (Fleck), this program is deployed to the user's machine.
Next, i have both a website and an android app running Websocket **clients** (in javascript and java respectively). The clients know how to connect to the server (queried from database via php).

So this way a direct connection is made from the client to the server, without going thru a website or anything, this is primarly since it can contain sensitve information and not having the website having to touch that is a giant plus! The website itself is running HTTPS using a trusted certificate.

The c# Fleck server requires a pfx certificate for WSS, i tried making that using openSSL and the certificate i use for the website. But the browser silently drops the connection when a websocket certificate is no good. If i go to http**s**://localhost:port i get the expected browser warning that my domain isn't matching with the certificate, the same error is probably why the browser drops the websocket connection, since neither the user's PC or any computer/phone they connect from is using that domain.

If my above observations are correct, in essence i would need something like a trusted certificate with a variable domain. Does such a thing exist?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your architecture correctly you have:

- A Websocket server running on the clients personal computer, which is usually located behind some router/firewall inside some private network.
- Websocket clients on various places, especially inside an Android application and at the Webserver. These Websocket clients might be inside the same local network as the Websocket server, but might also be inside some external public network or inside some different private network.

Now you are trying to secure the communication between client and server by using WSS (i.e. Websockt over TLS) with some certificate for the Websocket server. And you want to use the same certificate for all Websocket endpoints and it should be shipped with the server application.

This kind of setup will not work for several reasons:

- Because the Websocket server is on a personal computer which mostly is inside some internal local network it will not be reachable from outside, unless the user adds  specific port forwarding rules for incoming connections at the router or firewall.
- If you want to use the same certificate for all server instances you would need to ship not only the certificate but also the matching private key with your Websocket server application. This means anybody might extract certificate and private key and use it for their own fake server or for a man-in-the-middle attack against your system.

Contrary to these problems the name in the certificate is actually not much of a problem, because you could simply use [certificate/public key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) against this fixed certificate instead of checking  the certificate chain and hostname. But again, I think the whole design is flawed.

Apart from that, [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask questions about a security architecture.

Answer (score 1):

No.. having a variable domain would for all intents and purposes break the idea of "trust".  If anyone could use your certificate... then *anyone* could use your certificate.  Do your users know you are setting a webserver up on their machine?  Keep in mind.. the user would have to open up their firewall to the server hosting this webserver.

Likely your best option is to just set your client code to disregard the certificate issue and continue on.